# Add label to org-agenda-bulk-custom-functions

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Custom functions added do not have a label so it might be hard to remember them.

[image: Custom functions have no label]

After looking at the source, it looks like the only option is to provide your own implementation of `org-agenda-bulk-action`.

I hope to be proven wrong though.

Comment: You might want to send this to the [Org mode mailing list](https://orgmode.org/community.html) as a request for enhancement.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to hack around pretty much everything in elisp using a combination of temporarily rebinding functions and advice.

In this case, you could add some advice around `org-agenda-bulk-action` to redefine `char-to-string` in its body, which `org-agenda-bulk-action` calls to format the custom binding message.  This local version of `char-to-string` checks an alist for additional messages, (`"[D<+day>]"` for your `?D` binding).

```
;; give custom keys an extra message
(defvar my-custom-mappings '((?D . "<+Day>")))

;; redefine `char-to-string' in the body of `org-agenda-bulk-action'
(define-advice org-agenda-bulk-action (:around (orig-fn &rest args) "custom-msg")
  (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'char-to-string)
             (lambda (char)
               (let ((msg (assoc char my-custom-mappings)))
                 (if msg (format "%c%s" (car msg) (cdr msg))
                   (format "%c" char))))))
    (apply orig-fn args)))
```

Of course, this is fairly brittle with respect to changes in the source.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this soon and accept it if it works for me. I'll also send a feature request since that's probably whats needed here.